# How to connect to a VPS without SSH.

Tags: ssh, centos, vps

I have a fresh VPS I just bought, for playing only. No risk of any kind involved, so I noticed that due to my slow connection I have to wait seconds to finish writing commands and opening/closing files. So, I would like to know if I can connect to my VPS without ssh?

Putty gives me an option to connect as `raw`, which upon choosing I can not log in to my VPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/).

It is optimized for slow and buggy network connections and does some neat tricks to allow comfortable working with such a connection, i.e. it displays characters you type on the fly and not after the server sends them back to you.

Opening files will sadly still be slow, but commands are better.

Answer (score 2):

Your host can be offering KVMoIP which allows you to connect to your server without SSH.

Comment: I am using digital host, and I don't see such option. But I just realized that what I am looking maybe a telnet connection. Since, telnet does not encrypt the data, that would improve the speed of the connection.

Comment: @Contax I'd say, try it! :)

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if I hadn't tried it :) It does not work for me, I could be missing something.